# How to make JUnit annotations work in SOAP UI?

Tags: junit4, soapui

I am trying to port my JUnit test scripts into SOAP UI.  Since SOAP UI supports Java, I thought it will support JUnit as well.  I have placed the JUnit Jar in 'ext' folder.  When I run the test, I could see that the annotation @Test is not being recognized by SOAP UI.

I got the below error:

> Script1.groovy: 9: Invalid constructor format. Remove 'void' as the
>   return type if you want a constructor, or use a different name if you
>   want a method. at line: 9 column: 4. File: Script1.groovy @ line 9,
>   column 4.
>         @Test

Am I doing it entirely wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using please? Its hard to tell if you're doing something wrong without seeing the code. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code (since it hasn't been posted as of writing this), you probably don't need to have a return type of `void`, especially on the constructor.

I'm still a little confused by your question though; are you trying to run JUnit from inside of SoapUI (it appears that way from the error message you are getting) or do you want to run it from a Java class, using JUnit and calling SoapUI. If you are doing the latter, try the following example of the format that **[should work](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.ca/2012/10/testing-web-services-from-junit-using.html#.UdduGz773HF)**:

```
public class CalculatorServiceTestCase  {

    @Test
    public void testCalculatorService() throws Exception {
        SoapUITestCaseRunner testCaseRunner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
        SoapUIMockServiceRunner mockServiceRunner = new SoapUIMockServiceRunner();

        testCaseRunner.setProjectFile("src/test/resources/calculator-soapui-project.xml");
        mockServiceRunner.setProjectFile("src/test/resources/calculator-soapui-project.xml");
        mockServiceRunner.run();
        testCaseRunner.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying the former actually - Run JUnit from inside of SoapUI.